# while I were trying to make carousel slider of posts in laravel I have get an error that is

Tags: php, laravel, slider, carousel, blogs

```
@extends('layouts.app')
<style type="text/css">
  .avatar{
  border-radius: 100%;
  max-width:100px;
}
</style> 
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset">
             @if(count($errors) > 0)
                 @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                     <div class="alert alert-danger">{{$error}}</div>
                 @endforeach
              @endif                      
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('response'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('response') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif 
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    @if(!empty($profile))
                    <img src="{{ $profile->profile_pic}}" class="avatar" alt="" >
                    @else 
                    <img src="{{ url('images/avatar.jpg')}}" class="avatar" alt="" >
                    @endif

                     @if(!empty($profile))
                       <p class="lead">{{ $profile->name}}</p>

                    @else 
                    <p></p>
                    @endif


                     @if(!empty($profile))
                   <p class="lead">{{ $profile->designation}}</p>
                    @else 
                    <p></p>
                    @endif

                   </div>






                   <div class="group-home-slideshow">
  <div class="home-slideshow-inner col-sm-12">
    <div class="home-slideshow">
      <div id="home_main-slider" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            @foreach($posts as $post)
                <li data-target="#home_main-slider" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"></li>
            @endforeach
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          @foreach($posts as $post)
          <div class="item image {{ $loop->first ? ' active' : '' }}">
            <img src="{{url('images')}}/{{$slider->photo}}" alt="slider" title="Image Slideshow">
            <div class="slideshow-caption position-right">
              <div class="slide-caption">
                <div class="group-caption">
                  <div class="content">
                    @if(count($posts) >0)
                       @foreach($posts->all() as $post)
                        <h4>{{$post->post_title}}</h4>
                        <img src="{{$post->post_image}}" alt="">

                        <p>{{ substr($post->post_body , 0 , 150)}}</p>

                  </div>
                   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                          <li role="presentation">
                            <a href='{{ url("/view/{$post->id}") }}'>
                              <span class="fa fa-eye">  View</span>
                            </a>
                          </li>

                           <li role="presentation">
                            <a href='{{ url("/edit/{$post->id}") }}'>
                              <span class="fa fa-edit">  Edit</span>
                            </a>
                          </li>
                           <li role="presentation">
                            <a href='{{ url("/delete/{$post->id}") }}'>
                              <span class="fa fa-trash-alt">  Delete</span>

                            </a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#home_main-slider" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#home_main-slider" data-slide="next">
          <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

i have error of ErrorException thrown with message

> "syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or
>   else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\home.blade.php)"

Stacktrace:

> 0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\storage\framework\views\78e09b18337fc09824b99eedafb8d772ac9d9d5d.php:125

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed one `if` and one `foreach`:

```
<div class="content">
@if(count($posts) >0)
   @foreach($posts->all() as $post)
    <h4>{{$post->post_title}}</h4>
    <img src="{{$post->post_image}}" alt="">

    <p>{{ substr($post->post_body , 0 , 150)}}</p>
   @endforeach
@endif
</div>
```